# Zookeeper cannot create new znodes

Tags: docker, apache-zookeeper

I run a zookeeper container in Docker and start a local client to connect it but I just can't create a new znode.

[image]

Comment: While the image is helpful, can you put any relevant info into your question? Like, what you tried, and what errors you encountered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are violate the API

```
create /(?znode) value
```

For example, in your case you can try:

```
create /test init
```

Comment: Thank you! That's the problem.